# Is if(x) same as if(x==true)?

Tags: java, if-statement

Ok, so let's say I have an if statement and a boolean x:

```
if (x) {
    // some stuff
}
```

What happens here? Does this mean the same thing as `if(x == true)` ?

Comment: yes, yes it does.

Comment: Okay thanks, I've been seeing a lot of this used in code and I was always wondering.

Comment: Semantically, it is equivalent. At the bytecode level, it is not.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Really? Any good reason the compiler doesn't compile it to the same bytecode?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes. As for a good reason, I don't know. The `==` is an extra operation.

Comment: and at the other end if(!x) is the same as `if(x != true)` or `if(x == false)`

Comment: It means exactly the same, but whether the same code is generated depends on the compiler. It should be, but don't count on it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529344/are-there-good-reasons-for-x-true

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes,

```
if(x) {

}
```

is the succinct equivalent of

```
if(x == true) {

}
```

As @Sotirios points out, they are different at the bytecode level.  Consider the following Java class:

```
class Test { 
   public void foo() { 
      boolean x = true;
      if(x == true) { 
      }
   }
}
```

emits:

```
  public void foo();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iload_1       
       3: iconst_1      
       4: if_icmpne     7
       7: return
```

vs

```
class Test { 
   public void foo() { 
      boolean x = true;
      if(x) { 
      }
   }
}
```

which emits:

```
  public void foo();
    Code:
       0: iconst_1      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iload_1       
       3: ifeq          6
       6: return
```

I don't think this has any bearing on the performance or correctness of the program.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.

`if` checks if the condition is true, and if it is, executes the body statement. So `x` needs to be a `boolean` expression.

In fact `x` is equivalent to `x == true` if `x` is a boolean expression, so you should use `x` as it is more concise. This becomes clearer if the variable has a proper name for a boolean, e.g.

```
if (this.isVisible()) {
    this.hide();
}
```

vs.

```
if (this.isVisible() == true) {
    this.hide();
}
```

The first one is better to read.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means the same thing as if you had if(x == true).

Answer (score 3):

If `x` can be resolved as a boolean, and the value is "true", the "other stuff" will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is same as `if(x == true)`. In fact `if(x)` is recommended.

See the examples in [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) in The Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The return of both is a boolean, in this case both return true

For example:

x= true.

Evaluating:

a) if(x)

b) if(x==true)

Both return true, the first because is the value directly and the second because the expression it is true (true==true).

Hope this can help you too...

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/boolean_values.html

Answer (score 2):

Jep this is right.

There is also a short form that could be interesting for you:

It means if x is true then return true, else return false.

```
(x) ? return true : return false;
```

Comment: `x ? true : false` is just as redundant as `x == true`, and they're both equivalent to simply `x`.

Comment: Well i just wrote this example to make sure that he knows this version of an if statement too. It isn't a example for production.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

An `if` statement takes a boolean expression as its condition. That can be the result of an operator which returns a boolean value such as `==`, or that can be a boolean variable. Basically, a boolean expression is anything which you can assign to a boolean variable:

```
boolean b = ?;
```

Therefore, `x == true` is somewhat redundant, as `x` on its own already suffices: those two boolean expressions are *equivalent*. It's quite common for new programmers though to write the `== true`, as it "reads" more naturally: *if `x` is true, then do...*

However, you should actually read that as *if `(x == true)` is true, then do...* as that's what's *actually* happening. Here, you see where the redundancy comes from. More experienced programmers know this and prefer writing `x` and `!x` as opposed to `x == true` and `x == false` respectively. It doesn't matter for the compiler, but it matters for the programmer/maintainer when he has to read:

```
if ( ((x == true) && (y == true)) || (z == false) ) { ... }
```

as opposed to:

```
if ( (x && y) || !z ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean the same thing as `if(x == true)`?

Yes `if(x == true)` will give same results as `if (x)`. It is based on simple logic:

- if `x` is `true` condition `x == true` is same as `true == true` which is evaluated to `true` which is same as original value of `x`
- if `x` is `false` condition `x == true` is same as `false == true` which is evaluated to `false` which again is same as original value of `x`

So regardless of value of `x` expression `if (x==true)` is equivalent to `if (x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are **Same** & **True**. And give you the same result.

```
if(x) is more appropriate
```

Reason, In Programming language, any number but not **0** is considered as **True**.

Suppose I take a number which is **5**:

```
if(x) or if(5)
```

because **5** is not equal to **0** or you can say **5!=0** that why it's True.