# If statement gives condition is always true

Tags: android, if-statement

When I use `if` statement it gives me that the condition x is always true  although I use the same code in another app and it works, but in this case I use it in  `onOptionsItemSelected` method for my menu ,So can someone help ?

```
public class Wellcome extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wellcome);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chang_language, menu);
    return true;
}
 Boolean x=true;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (id == R.id.arabic) {
       if (x =true) {
           setLocale("en");
           x = false;
       } else  if (x =false) {
           setLocale("ar");
           x = true;
       }
     return true;
   }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    java.util.Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Wellcome.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
       }
     }
```

Comment: an assignation 'x =true' is different than a comparison 'x == true' an assignation is evaluated as true almost always so your if will always go into it. You should use comparisons to your ifs

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a variable instead of just use the `Boolean` Value that is a logical error instead you should use `x` itself in a statement as:

```
if (x) {
       setLocale("en");
       x = false;
   } else{
       setLocale("ar");
       x = true;
   }
```

And job is done! If the value of `x` is `true` the `if` statement will execute itself but if `x` is `false` the `else` will execute there is no need to compare using `=` or `==` just use the boolean value itself. Also its my advice use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`class. For performance!

Comment: use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` class  @MohamedAhmed  please!

Comment: Now @MohamedAhmed I am worried may be the problem is not in the if statement try checking errors elsewhere in your code but there is no problem with that part!

Comment: I attached the all activity code because of that because I feel that if statement is fine .... its work with me before . do you have any suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

Bypassing the comparison operator error `=` instead of `==` (`==` is the correct, please update your code), which is addressed from the other answers, the flow of your program leads to never reach (at least the user experience part) the part where you set the `x` variable to `false` in the `if` statement.

```
setLocale("en");
x = false; // -> this part is not reached because you start a new activity of the same class in the setLocale above
```

More specifically, the `setLocale` method which is called in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method, restarts your activity via the following code:

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Wellcome.class);
startActivity(refresh);
```

Since the `Wellcome` activity is started from the `refresh` intent, a new `Wellcome` activity appears on top of the old one, and of course this new activity's field variable `x` will be instantiated to `true`,

```
Boolean x=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using correct operator.

- assignment operator (=)
- comparision operator (==)

so use == instead of =

`if (x =true)` is wrong here, you should use `if (x == true)`

similarly 
`if (x = false)` is wrong here, you should use `if (x == false)`

Comment: Downvote because you *shouldn't* use `(x == true)` or `(x == false)`. Just use `(x)` or `(!x)`.

Comment: if(x == true)  and if(x) : both are same. Please check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301775/is-ifx-same-as-ifx-true

Comment: No. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014718/which-one-is-safer-to-use-true-or-false. Do not complicate it.

Comment: Man, you are referring wrong link, the link you provided is for the C language while this question is for Java language (in Android ). Better to run a sample program and compare yourself to clear it. Or please check the link which i provided in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to initialize the boolean variable as true and returning `true`, I would also advise you to use `boolean` instead of `Boolean` to avoid creating new Boolean objects (I'm assuming `x` is primitive).

But please try:

`boolean x = false;`

```
if (!x) {
           setLocale("en");
           x = true;            } 
           else  if (x)
        {
           setLocale("ar");
           x = false;           }

     return x;
```

Comment: I did it  and still always false .

Comment: The default value of a boolean is false, but as mentioned by other comments. The fault might possibly be elsewhere in your code try inserting the method within a try-catch statement or initializing the variable inside the method.